# Only one User can`t access to intranet site (iis,asp.net), but has access to Internet and another intranet site

Tags: asp.net, iis

sorry for my english.
I have an Intranet site in iis server. It's run ok, and users can access but... 
Problem: a user (only one), from his PC, can't access to site. The browser (I test with Firefox,Opera,Chrome and IE) remains "Connecting",then appear:
"The connection was reset The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments. If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection.
    If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web."

The user write the rigth site's IP

Somebody have any idea about what's the reason? I turned off firewall and antivirus.

thks!

EDIT

Now, I put my site in other web server, accessible from Internet and the problem again is that this User can't access to my site from his PC but the others can do it. Remember that the User can access to sites on the web (like Google,youtube, etc)

EDIT

Now, I test with Google Developer tool and see that if I go to "10.0.0.14/Content/bootstrap.min.css" , it is downloaded and the browser show it. But others files can not, for exemple 10.0.0.14/Content/bootstrap-theme.min.css" and "10.0.0.14/WebResource.axd?d=pynGkmcFUV13He1Qd6_TZL-7w4aBefoL2eZ1I2H7fFtNR4jTJYcE2P4_ophzfnhFz0gMjaZDCvUBujIOoQywmw2&t=635145251460000000".

Sometime when I go to the site (10.0.0.14) I see that some files are downloaded but others (like bootstrap-theme.min.css) are pending so at the end can't to access to the site.

Comment: sounds like a network issue. Are you sure the computer is allowed to see the IP in question? Or maybe DNS issue if you access the site via a URL instead of IP?

Comment: yes, I do "ping" to the IP from his PC and is OK.

Comment: Did you check internet proxy settings on user's machine?

Comment: @PankajKapare, yes, is OK

Answer (score 0):

I understood your problem. All can access your site. But only one cant access it. Which may be the firewall problem. Please Turn off windows firewall, then it may work fine.

Comment: Also provide steps to Turn off firewall for a great answer.